# dacpac installation failed with Unable to reconnect to database: Execution Timeout Expired

Tags: c#, sql-server, dac

when publishing a dacpac using DacServices.Deploy in C#, getting timeout error.
Code recently migrated to .NET core. We're publishing into a new SQL Server 2022 database and this is first time we are deploying to SQL server.

code

```
                        var package = DacPackage.Load(dacpacPath);

                        if (package == null)
                        {
                            throw new Exception("Error loading DACPAC");
                        }

                        Log.Info($"DACPAC loaded....: Version='{package.Version}', Name='{package.Name}'");

                        Log.Info("Deploying DACPAC to server...");

                        var options = new DacDeployOptions()
                        {
                            BlockOnPossibleDataLoss = true
                        };

                        var services = new DacServices(setup.ConnectionString);

                        services.Message += Services_Message;
                        services.ProgressChanged += Services_ProgressChanged;

                        var builder = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder(setup.ConnectionString);

                        services.Deploy(package: package, targetDatabaseName: builder.InitialCatalog, upgradeExisting: false, options);

                        Log.Info("DACPAC deployed to server.");
```

below is the exception details.

```
Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac.DacServicesException: An error occurred during deployment plan generation. Deployment cannot continue.
 ---> Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.Sql.Deployment.DeploymentFailedException: Unable to reconnect to database: Execution Timeout Expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.
 ---> Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.Sql.SchemaModel.SqlReverseEngineerException: Unable to reconnect to database: Execution Timeout Expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.
 ---> Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Execution Timeout Expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.
 ---> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (258): Unknown error 258
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.TryConsumeMetaData()
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.get_MetaData()
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds, RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString, Boolean isInternal, Boolean forDescribeParameterEncryption, Boolean shouldCacheForAlwaysEncrypted)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean isAsync, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite, Boolean inRetry, SqlDataReader ds, Boolean describeParameterEncryptionRequest)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean& usedCache, Boolean asyncWrite, Boolean inRetry, String method)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader()
   at Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.Sql.SchemaModel.SqlReverseEngineerImpl.ExecutePopulators(Tuple`2 connectionTuple, IList`1 populators, Int32 totalPopulatorsCount, Int32 startIndex, Boolean progressAlreadyUpdated, ReverseEngineerOption option, SqlReverseEngineerRequest request)
ClientConnectionId:b869fd60-a7a4-4baa-9e6f-0c985fa1b68e
Error Number:-2,State:0,Class:11
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.Sql.SchemaModel.SqlReverseEngineerImpl.ExecutePopulatorsInPass(SqlReverseEngineerConnectionContext context, ReverseEngineerOption option, SqlReverseEngineerRequest request, Int32 totalCount, Tuple`2[] populatorsArray)
   at Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.Sql.SchemaModel.SqlReverseEngineerImpl.PopulateBatch(SqlReverseEngineerConnectionContext context, SqlSchemaModel model, ReverseEngineerOption option, ErrorManager errorManager, SqlReverseEngineerRequest request, SqlImportScope importScope)
   at Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.Sql.SchemaModel.SqlReverseEngineer.PopulateAll(SqlReverseEngineerConnectionContext context, ReverseEngineerOption option, ErrorManager errorManager, Boolean filterManagementScopedElements, SqlImportScope importScope, Boolean optimizeForQuery, ModelStorageType modelType)
   at Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.Sql.Deployment.SqlDeploymentEndpointServer.ImportDatabase(SqlReverseEngineerConstructor constructor, DeploymentEngineContext context, ErrorManager errorManager)
   at Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.Sql.Deployment.SqlDeploymentEndpointServer.CreateNewModel(ErrorManager errors, DeploymentEngineContext context)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue is solved, I was using wrong connection string.